# Erro ao fazer envio de json via $http

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic

Estou tentando enviar um json via $http.get, mas está retornando erro no console "500 (Internal Server Error)" sistema.tecnologia.ws/pedidoGravar.asp:1
Este erro é no sistema ASP ou na requisição $http?
Segue o código da requisição

```
    $http({
       method: 'GET',
       url: 'http://sistema.tecnologia.ws/pedidoGravar.asp',
       data: JSON.stringify($scope.recuperaSeuPedido),
       headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
     }).then(function successCallback(response) {
         console.log(response.data)
         console.log("enviou");
       }, function errorCallback(response) {
         console.log(response.data)
         console.log("nao enviou");
       });
```

Eu desabilitei o $http e fiz em js puro e retorna o mesmo erro. Segue o código abaixo

```
   xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
     var url = "http://sistema.tecnologia.ws/pedidoGravar.asp";
     xhr.open("GET", url, true);
     xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8");
     xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
         if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
             console.log(xhr.responseText);
         }
         console.log(xhr.responseText);
     }
     xhr.send("json=" + encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify($scope.recuperaSeuPedido)));
```

Comment: Não conheço Angular.js nem tenho a mínima ideia do que seja "ionic", mas...o método não deveria ser POST ?

Comment: ja tentei tbm, mais retorna o mesmo erro

Comment: O erro está no arquivo *.asp ou no seu servidor. Se você exibir o código do pedidoGravar.asp ficará melhor para ajudar.

Comment: Seu servidor suporta ASP?

Comment: Sim sim...ja corrigi o erro...vo postar o código pra ajudar a galera que precisar tbm

Answer (score 0):

Era erro de informação. Vo postar o código aqui, pra ajudar a galera que tiver o mesmo problema

```
    $http({
     //Method alterado
     method:'POST',
     url:'http://sistema.tecnologia.ws/pedidoGravar.asp',
     //Data alterado
     data: "json=" + encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify($scope.recuperaSeuPedido)),
     //Headers alterado
     headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'}
  })
  .then(function successCallback(response){
        console.log(response.data)
        console.log("enviou");
  }),
  function errorCallback(response){
     console.log(response.data)
     console.log("nao enviou");
  }
```